# count no of elements in nested documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have data in below format

```
 {
        "result" : [ 
            {                    
                "advertiser" : "lordandtaylor"
                ,
                "networks" : [ 
                    "Pepperjam"
                ],
                "publishers" : [ 
                    "best-price.com", 
                    "allthingswholesale.com"
                ]
            }]
    }
```

Now I want to display this in below format

```
{"advertiser":"lordandtaylor" , "networks":"1" , "publishers":"2"}
```

Comment: This exact situation is described in great detail here: http://collidercreative.com/how-to-get-the-total-count-from-nested-arrays-within-mongodb-documents/

Comment: Hi Pete, but I want both array count. I have array of advertisers on which I want to run this

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

```
db.link.aggregate([
{
    {   
    $project : { _id: 0, advertiser : "$_id.advertiser", networks : {$size : "$networks"} , advertisers : {$size : "$publishers"} } 
}
]);
```